# PHP 7 connecting to Informix database

Tags: php, database, informix

Is there anyway to connect to a Informix database with PHP 7 on windows?

I have tried installing the PDO_INFORMIX 1.3.2 driver, but it doesn't have a .dll for PHP 7: https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_INFORMIX

I have no clue how to compile a .dll from the .tgz

Any ideas?

Comment: Tried to compile it with visual studio, but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this website, it may help you:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-informix.connection.php

Comment: Already read the whole documentation on php.net, but I need the PDO_INFORMIX driver installed first. Which I can't because there is no dll available for PHP 7

Comment: Ok, I will take a look at this.